# Out of Memory when Directory.GetFiles

Tags: vb.net, memory, imagelist

I'm trying to add images on an ImageList collection, but I'm getting this annoying "Out of Memory" exception. I have read some others questions about it, but I don't think that my images are corrupted. The images are Monochromatic BMP (for use in label printers) and have less than 1kb.

```
For Each path As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Public\Nitek\Imagens Tratadas")
   ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path))
Next
```

There are only two images on this directory. There is something I can do?

**EDIT:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/39RNz.png - This is one of those pictures.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your code is fine. There is probably a problem with one of your images. Try to put a Try...Catch block for each one of the images (inside the For Each Loop)

Comment: If there are other files in the directory (e.g. a Thumbs.db file, which will normally be hidden) then your program will try to load those into the ImageList too. You don't want to do that. If you use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on each file and check it is of a type which you want, you should be able to avoid the error.

Comment: Andrew Morton, it was a 'Thumbs.db' file indeed. I will use the Path.GetExtension to check the files. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx

Managed GDI+ has built-in encoders and decoders that support the following file types:

```
BMP

GIF

JPEG

PNG

TIFF
```

The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an OutOfMemoryException exception.

You could try saving the file in a different format to see if it works (like jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the contribution of Andrew Morton, I could resolve this issue. I had to create an condition to add images on my ImageList.

```
For Each caminho As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Public\Nitek\Imagens") 
    If Path.GetExtension(caminho) = ".bmp" Then
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(caminho))
    End If
Next
```

Using the `Path.GetExtension` attribute, is possible to override the Thumbs.db file.

Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :) You can do even better: as you only want files with an extension of `.bmp`, you could use `Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Public\Nitek\Imagens", "*.bmp")`.